# Cocos js - Android web browser shown blurry images

Tags: javascript, android-webview, cocos2d-js

I had made a game using cocos2d-js. Then compiled it by command `cocos run -p web -m release`. Everything is fine on PC and iOS web browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari) but on Android, all above browsers shown very low quality of images, they became blurry. I can not figure out what was happened. Here is two compared images for iOS and Android, thanks for pay your attention.

[iOS vs Android on web browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPkmM.jpg)

Comment: did you use separate set of images for android? is it looking good in debug mode?  by running "cocos run -p web" how is is showing?

Comment: @PrachiJoshi: Thanks for answering my question. I used same resources for all devices at 1334x750. The same issue is happened when run on debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Please use separate resources  according to your resolutions

Comment: Can you please explain in details how can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: you write a javascript before your gamecanvas in html to detect the resolution of your screen, make the required number if resources sets and according to the screen size, set the path of appropriate resources folder in your resources.js/json file you can refer [responsive images](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp)